# Entity Framework many to many, insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

This is how my entities look like:

[image]

My question is how to add `Comment` object to `News` object and how to update and delete `Comment` of news?

Here is the `News` class:

```
News news = db.News.SingleOrDefault(n => n.NewsId == Id);
```

Comment: In my opinion, your model should be revised. I don't see the need for your `NewsComment` entity. It does not hold any useful information. Make `Comments` the navigation property for `News`. If it is many-to-many, the relation would be handled internally, without the need for the `NewsComment` entity.

Comment: Is this an example or real schema?  I ask because it doesn't make sense from a user experience that a Comment can be applied to multiple news items.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I have seen this type of model used before (specifically for comments). it is implemented with a relation table, which implies many-to-many, but in practice it is one-to-many because one comment should NOT be attached to multiple parent objects.

Comment: @MrAnderson so why the added complexity?  What benefit is there of the intermediate table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your model stands now, you can do it like this:

```
News news = db.News.SingleOrDefault(n => n.NewsId == Id);
Comment comment = new Comment { Body = "This is my comment" };
NewsComment newsComment = new NewsComment { News = news, Comment = comment };
news.NewsComments.Add(newsComment);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Personally, I would adjust your model to take away the `NewsComment` entity. Your `News` entity would have a many-to-many property `Comments`, and the relation table would be handled internally. Your code would then become:

```
News news = db.News.SingleOrDefault(n => n.NewsId == Id);
Comment comment = new Comment { Body = "This is my comment" };
news.Comments.Add(comment);
db.SaveChanges();
```

**Edit:** To delete a comment with your current model, remove it from the collection property:

```
News news = db.News.SingleOrDefault(n => n.NewsId == Id);
NewsComment commentIDontWant = news.NewsComments.First(nc => nc.Comment.Body == "Bad Comment");
news.NewsComments.Remove(commentIDontWant);
db.SaveChanges();
```